# Customizing size of django admin portal text fields

Tags: django

How do I make a text field in the django admin portal bigger? Right now its one line, I want to make it about 5, so I can type in a small paragraph and see the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your admin.py :

1. import the forms class
2. define a new forms.Textarea
3. in your ModelAdmin class, override the form field

for example if you only want 1 row in your text area :

```
class RichTextEditorWidget(forms.Textarea):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        attrs = kwargs.setdefault('attrs', {})
        attrs.setdefault('cols', 60)
        attrs.setdefault('rows',1)

    super(RichTextEditorWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        formfield_overrides = {
            models.TextField: {'widget' : RichTextEditorWidget},
        }

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/